# Login Page can not find SQLite database in Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello I am working on basic login and create account app. The app stores the information locally to a .db3 file when the user makes a account. The issue I'm having is when I go to login to the app using the email address and password I just created within the app I get a error saying it can't find the database. here is my login page code:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Database.Sqlite;
using SQLite;

namespace FirstApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "CharterChallange Login", Theme = "@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class LoginActivity : Activity
    {
        EditText txtusername;
        EditText txtPassword;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginPage);

            //Initializing button from layout
            Button login = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.login);
            Button adduser = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.adduser);
            txtusername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.userName);
            txtPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.password);

            //Login button click action
            login.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

                try
                {
                    //I think the issue is here: 
                    string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "DB.db3"); //Call Database  
                    var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
                    var Login = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                    var data = db.Table<AddressBook>(); //Call Table  
                    var data1 = data.Where(x => x.Email == txtusername.Text && x.Password == txtPassword.Text).FirstOrDefault(); //Linq Query  
                    if (data1 != null)
                    {
                        StartActivity(Login);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Username or Password invalid", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }




            };



            //Create User button click action
            adduser.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                var createUser = new Intent(this, typeof(AddEditAddressBookActivity));
                StartActivity(createUser);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my DB helper class where the database is being created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Database.Sqlite;
using Android.Database;
using System.Collections;

namespace FirstApp
{
  public class AddressBookDbHelper: SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private const string APP_DATABASENAME = "DB.db3";
        private const int APP_DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        public AddressBookDbHelper(Context ctx):
            base(ctx, APP_DATABASENAME, null, APP_DATABASE_VERSION)
        {

        }

        public override void OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.ExecSQL(@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AddressBook(
                            Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                            FullName TEXT NOT NULL,
                            Email   TEXT NULL,
                            Password TEXT)");


        }

        public override void OnUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            db.ExecSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AddressBook");
            OnCreate(db);
        }

        //Retrive All Contact Details
        public IList<AddressBook> GetAllContacts()
        {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.ReadableDatabase;

           ICursor c =  db.Query("AddressBook", new string[] { "Id", "FullName", "Email", "Password" }, null, null, null, null, null);

            var contacts = new List<AddressBook>();

            while (c.MoveToNext())
            {
                contacts.Add(new AddressBook
                        {
                            Id = c.GetInt(0),
                            FullName = c.GetString(1),
                            Email = c.GetString(2),
                            Password = c.GetString(3) }); 
            }

            c.Close();
            db.Close();

            return contacts;
        }


        //Retrive All Contact Details
        public IList<AddressBook> GetContactsBySearchName(string nameToSearch)
        {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.ReadableDatabase;

            ICursor c = db.Query("AddressBook", new string[] { "Id", "FullName", "Email", "Password" }, "upper(FullName) LIKE ?", new string[] {"%"+ nameToSearch.ToUpper() +"%"}, null, null, null, null);

            var contacts = new List<AddressBook>();

            while (c.MoveToNext())
            {
                contacts.Add(new AddressBook
                {
                    Id = c.GetInt(0),
                    FullName = c.GetString(1),
                    Email = c.GetString(2),
                    Password = c.GetString(3)
                });
            }

            c.Close();
            db.Close();

            return contacts;
        }

        //Add New Contact
        public void AddNewContact(AddressBook contactinfo)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.WritableDatabase;
            ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
            vals.Put("FullName", contactinfo.FullName);
            vals.Put("Email", contactinfo.Email);
            vals.Put("Password", contactinfo.Password);
            db.Insert("AddressBook", null, vals);
        }

        //Get contact details by contact Id
        public ICursor getContactById(int id)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.ReadableDatabase;
            ICursor res = db.RawQuery("select * from AddressBook where Id=" + id + "", null);
            return res;
        }

        //Update Existing contact
        public void UpdateContact(AddressBook contitem)
        {
            if (contitem == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Obtain writable database
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.WritableDatabase;

            //Prepare content values
            ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
            vals.Put("FullName", contitem.FullName);
            vals.Put("Email", contitem.Email);
            vals.Put("Password", contitem.Password);


            ICursor cursor = db.Query("AddressBook",
                    new String[] {"Id", "FullName",  "Email", "Password" }, "Id=?", new string[] { contitem.Id.ToString() }, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null)
            {
                if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
                {
                    // update the row
                    db.Update("AddressBook", vals, "Id=?", new String[] { cursor.GetString(0) });
                }

                cursor.Close();
            }

        }


        //Delete Existing contact
        public void DeleteContact(string  contactId)
        {
            if (contactId == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Obtain writable database
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.WritableDatabase;

            ICursor cursor = db.Query("AddressBook",
                    new String[] { "Id", "FullName", "Email", "Password"}, "Id=?", new string[] { contactId }, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null)
            {
                if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
                {
                    // update the row
                    db.Delete("AddressBook", "Id=?", new String[] { cursor.GetString(0) });
                }

                cursor.Close();
            }

        }



    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!!! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why isn't your login page using the dbhelper class too?

Comment: How would I do that can you please explain?

Comment: add a Login method to dbhelper that includes all the db login logic.  Then call that from your login page.  The underlying problem is that dbhelper is (probably) using a different path for the db than you're using in your login page.  By placing all the db logic in one centralized class you reduce the chances of that happening.

Comment: @Phoneswapshop Show the code about how you added the new user account. You only posted the code about verifying the account from your db on the login page. This will cause using different paths to create different databases as what Jason said if you utilized helper class to add new accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that you need to provide a valid connection string.

Change

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
```

to

```
var db = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dpPath);
```